# Sharper Corners on Grouped UITableView Cells without Subclassing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

How can I create less rounded corners for my UITableviewCells in a grouped UITableView? I'm looking to lessen the corner radius of each grouping like in this app: *(I'm NOT trying to round the entire* `tableview`)

I've tried this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` but with no luck:

```
[cell.layer setCornerRadius:1.0];
```

[image]

Comment: have you thought about implementing a custom table view cell?

Comment: @user2277872 as noted in the subject heading, I'd rather not have to subclass

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a more sharper cornered cell, it would easiest to just edit the custom view of the cell. You can do this by using this line:

```
cell.backgroundView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds]
```

put this inside the

> cellForRowAtIndexPath

method